# (Hosted) Twitter Clone for Company internal use

Tags: twitter, saas

I'm searching for something that works like Twitter but for a closed group of users. I also want a SaaS offering, nt some software (e.g. status.net) which we have to install ourselfs.

I'm aware of

- present.ly - but they seem not to support any "payed" accounts (you get what you pay for)
- yammer.com - seem to have questionable business ethics regarding data ownership etc.

I thought there would be hundreds of other similar services but so far i found nothing. Any Suggestions/Experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been searching for this for a couple of days, and found status.net the best solution so far. You mentioned it in your question, have you checked their hosted solutions?

E.G. http://mozilla.status.net/

Answer (score 2):

Status.net does seem to provide a [hosted service](http://status.net/enterprise-network).

Comment: Thanks for the Pointer! Last Time I checked they didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a P2 Theme in wordpress Neat and elegant

Comment: That may actually be the simplest solution, if not the absolute most secure.

Answer (score 1):

[SocialCast](http://www.socialcast.com) is another solution that has a free tier as well as paid hosted, and paid behind the firewall version.  I've tried the free versions of SocialCast and Yammer.  I preferred Yammer, but not for any real good reason, just personal preference.